# Docker service performance vs individual container?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am running a server with Docker Swarm. But then, these days I questioned about Docker service performance. I don't even think that having more than 2 instances and scaling up replicas doesn't help docker-server performance.

For example:

> having a individual container in an instance
> vs
> docker service
> with 10 replicas

In my experience, Docker container with an individual container showed better performance(which is getting data from MySQL and sending back to fronted etc).

Am I misunderstanding about Docker container/service performance?

Comment: Have you measured it?  Is the MySQL backend a bottleneck?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah, I test it all many ways(like no swarm mode in two aws instances with single docker container etc), then concluded myself that ingress load balancing in docker-swarm mode  bother the performance of entire APIs(I don't know if because I have an external load balancer). Hope I will figure out how to stop load balancing in swarm mode or modify the ingress overlay network in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the point here.

Service replication is not here to solve *performance* issues but to solve **high availability** issues.
If one replicate fail, then the request will just fallback on the other replicates available. That's (one of) the reason of using an orchestrator.

Of course, using an orchestrator will slow down *a bit* the traffic but where not talking about a 50% drop of performance here !

In fact it's the same for everything, even in real life. Going to your local store to buy something is always faster than shopping online and wait for delivery. However, you're not sure that your local store has whatever you want to buy. At the opposite, if you go on a populare e-shop then you're almost certain that you'll get what you want at first try. You'll just have to wait a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

There are three questions in your question.

The answer to the first is "none" and to the two others is "it depends" :) Enough with the snarky-ness, let's have a look at what your asking...

**Q1: What's the performance-hit of a single container vs a service with 1 replica?**

A1: 0.000n%. Your single-replica service will just spin up ... a single replica. The reason the answer is 0.000n% is because Swarm requires a tiny bit of memory and cpu in the Docker engine, which might influence your overall performance

**Q2: What's the performance-hit of swarm networking?**

A2: Now you're comparing the networking performance of the communication caused by the Swarm Overlay networking system. Most of the time, the performance hit will be close to 0. The default overlay used by Swarm is VXLAN. There is a tiny performance hit, as each packet needs to be encapsulated/decapsulated. If you have a lot of replica's and a lot of short-lived connections (think: stateless api that gets a lot of requests), there might be some overhead involved with the ingress load-balancer. So "it depends"

**Q3: Single replica of the app, which consumes lots of cpu and ram vs multiple replicas of the app, each consuming a tiny bit of ram and cpu.**

A3: It depends, but this is not a Docker (swarm) question. Some apps (stateless, don't depend on 'single access' external services, getting hammered with lots of requests, will do great when run in parallel (horizontal scaling). Some will behave worse and need vertical scaling (few instances, lots of mem and cpu). Keep in mind that the vertical scaling gets hard past a certain point...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related to [SWARM Very poor performance for ingress network with lots of parallel requests](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35082)

> the swarm-mode ingress is handled by IPVS and the connections are dispatched to the backend tasks over the overlay ingress network. But since it is a single node setup, the performance dip cannot happen due to the VXLAN headers used in overlay network. The only possible reason could be IPVS and it might require performance tuning for your case.

For those who thinks it's a network issue, maybe using `mode:host` under the ports can help bypass the ipvs limitation (but then you need an external loadbalancer for your swarm)

```
ports:
   - target: 80
     published: 80
     protocol: tcp
     mode: host
```